# converting drawable resource image into bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap

I am trying to use the `Notification.Builder.setLargeIcon(bitmap)` that takes a bitmap image. I have the image I want to use in my drawable folder so how do I convert that to bitmap?

Answer (score 429, accepted):

You probably mean `Notification.Builder.setLargeIcon(Bitmap)`, right? :)

```
Bitmap largeIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.large_icon);
notBuilder.setLargeIcon(largeIcon);
```

This is a great method of converting resource images into Android `Bitmap`s.

Comment: Why not hit the "Edit" button and fix the question? (More a suggestion for the future - I already did it for this one... I'd suggest editing your answer to not criticize their typos. I'm not doing it for you.) On another note, +1 for having a working answer :)

Comment: I dont think this is right _as a general answer_ — at least not since Android started supporting vector drawables.

Comment: after implementing the solution I'm getting this ...
`... E/CommitToConfigurationOperation: Malformed snapshot token (size): 
... E/NotificationService: Not posting notification with icon==0: Notification(pri=0 contentView=null vibrate=null sound=content://settings/system/notification_sound defaults=0x0 flags=0x10 color=0x00000000 vis=PRIVATE)
... E/NotificationService: WARNING: In a future release this will crash the app:...`

Answer (score 49):

```
Drawable myDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.logo);
Bitmap myLogo = ((BitmapDrawable) myDrawable).getBitmap();
```

Since API 22 `getResources().getDrawable()` is deprecated, so we can use following solution.

```
Drawable vectorDrawable = VectorDrawableCompat.create(getResources(), R.drawable.logo,  getContext().getTheme());
Bitmap myLogo = ((BitmapDrawable) vectorDrawable).getBitmap();
```

Comment: It tells me bitmapDrawable cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: Hi @20Cents did you tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18218938/why-does-it-say-bitmap-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-type-in-this-case

Comment: Just press ctrl+shift+O if you are receiving cannot be resolved to a type for bitmapDrawable. Cheers!

Comment: Unfortunately this way crashes my app!

Comment: getDrawable is deprecated

Answer (score 14):

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.my_drawable);
```

`Context` can be your current `Activity`.

Comment: and for vector drawables?

Answer (score 9):

Here is another way to convert Drawable resource into Bitmap in android:

```
Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.input);
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)drawable).getBitmap();
```

Comment: How is yours different from AndyW solution ? it is the same!

Comment: I tried this and it produces an error that it can not be cast: ```java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable```

Answer (score 8):

First Create Bitmap Image

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.image);
```

now set bitmap in Notification Builder Icon....

```
Notification.Builder.setLargeIcon(bmp);
```

Answer (score 2):

If someone is looking for the Kotlin version for the large icon, you may use this

```
val largeIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.resources, R.drawable.my_large_icon)
```

Answer (score 0):

In `res/drawable` folder,

**1.** Create a new `Drawable Resources`.

**2.** Input file name.

A new file will be created inside the `res/drawable` folder.

Replace this code inside the newly created file and replace `ic_action_back` with your drawable file name.

```
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_back"
    android:tint="@color/color_primary_text" />
```

Now, you can use it with Resource ID, `R.id.filename`.

Answer (score 0):

**Try the following:**

```
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.your_image_id);
```