# Constructing a RatingBar using images loaded from the web

Tags: android, android-layout, ratingbar

I have a form which I'm dynamically generating from data I receive from a web service. This web service provides images which need to be used in the creation of input elements. I'm having difficuly in setting the `progressDrawable` of a `RatingBar`. Though XML I'm able to apply a custom image using the following as the `progressDrawable`:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+android:id/background" android:drawable="@drawable/custom_star" />
    <item android:id="@+android:id/secondaryProgress" android:drawable="@drawable/custom_star" />
    <item android:id="@+android:id/progress" android:drawable="@drawable/custom_star" />
</layer-list>
```

where `custom_star` is a simple .png image, and with `@android:style/Widget.RatingBar` as the RatingBar style. This works fine:

[image: Working start]

but I'm wanting to change `custom_star` dynamically.

In code, I have tried setting the progress drawable using a bitmap directly:

```
Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), downloadedImage);
ratingBar.setProgressDrawable(d);
```

and also by constructing a `layer-list`:

```
LayerDrawable layerDrawable = new LayerDrawable(new Drawable[] {
    getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.custom_star),
    getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.custom_star),             
    getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.custom_star)
});

layerDrawable.setId(0, android.R.id.background);
layerDrawable.setId(1, android.R.id.secondaryProgress);
layerDrawable.setId(2, android.R.id.progress);

ratingBar.setProgressDrawable(layerDrawable);
```

Neither works for me; both result in the `custom_star` drawable appearing once, stretched by the dimensions of the `RatingBar`:

[image]

Any ideas?

**Update:**

Luksprog's answer below has made an improvement, but I'm still having a couple of issues. Now, the star drawable is not stretched and the value can be set by touch, but it appears as so with 3/5 selected:

[image: no secondary]

and 5/5 selected:

[image: too many stars]

I believe the scaling of the images can be fixed with a few tweaks, but annoyingly the `secondaryProgress` drawable doesn't seem to be set - the drawable used for the greyed out not-selected stars. Without that, it's not very usable.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Any ideas?

When using the default `progressDrawable` or a `progressDrawable` set through a theme all will be ok as in the constructor for the `RatingBar`(its superclass `ProgressBar` to be more precise) widget a method will be called to "make tiles" from that drawable. When using the `setProgressDrawable` method this doesn't happen and if you pass a simple `BitmapDrawable` or a `LayerDrawable`(with simple `BitmapDrawables`) that `Drawable` will simply be stretched to cover the widget's background area(what you see know).

In order to make it work you would need to manually do what the `RatingBar` does at start, create the tiles along with the `ClipDrawables` that it uses. I've written a method for this, following the source code of the `ProgressBar` widget:

```
private Drawable buildRatingBarDrawables(Bitmap[] images) {
    final int[] requiredIds = { android.R.id.background,
            android.R.id.secondaryProgress, android.R.id.progress };
    final float[] roundedCorners = new float[] { 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5 };
    Drawable[] pieces = new Drawable[3];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        ShapeDrawable sd = new ShapeDrawable(new RoundRectShape(
                roundedCorners, null, null));
        BitmapShader bitmapShader = new BitmapShader(images[i],
                Shader.TileMode.REPEAT, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
        sd.getPaint().setShader(bitmapShader);
        ClipDrawable cd = new ClipDrawable(sd, Gravity.LEFT,
                ClipDrawable.HORIZONTAL);
        if (i == 0) {
            pieces[i] = sd;
        } else {
            pieces[i] = cd;
        }
    }
    LayerDrawable ld = new LayerDrawable(pieces);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        ld.setId(i, requiredIds[i]);
    }
    return ld;
}
```

Then you would use the `LayerDrawable` returned by this method with the `setProgressDrawable` method. The `RatingBar` set its width multiplying the width of one of the state bitmaps with the number of stars, so in order to show the right amount of stars this has to be calculated as well.

Comment: Great stuff. This is definitely working for me, although I can't seem to get it to set secondaryProgress. The stars appear when clicked, but the grayed-out unselected background ones don't appear (I'm using a different drawable, R.drawable.star_off).

Comment: While your exact solution didn't work for me, I checked out the [Android source code for ProgressBar](http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.3_r1/android/widget/ProgressBar.java/) as you suggested, and ripping out the tileify() method worked great for me. Thanks!

Comment: @blork Sorry about the code I posted(didn't had much time), it didn't fully replicate that method(I somehow lost that `clip` flag). I'm sure you managed to also make the stars have the correct size. The `RatingBar` sets its width by multiplying the width of one of the bitmaps with the number of stars(calculating this in the `onMeasure` method of a custom `RatingBar` should show the right amount of stars).

Comment: Fan-freaking-tastic. Been trying to work out a fix for this for days. This is very well written. Just remember that you MUST pass 3 bitmaps else you will get an outofbounds exception. Also, for those who are trying to use Drawables and realize you can't pass them, just convert using this method: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8717333/converting-drawable-resource-image-into-bitmap

Answer (score 0):

Your ids are wrong, you have to set 
@android:id/background
@android:id/secondaryProgress
@android:id/progress

You can also define a drawable in xml containing your customization

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+android:id/background"
          android:drawable="@drawable/star_empty" />
    <item android:id="@+android:id/secondaryProgress"
          android:drawable="@drawable/star_empty" />
    <item android:id="@+android:id/progress"
          android:drawable="@drawable/star_full" />
</layer-list>
```

And you can use `setMax` on the RatingBar object to set the maximum amount of stars that can be displayed

Answer (score 0):

It's much easier with such solution:

```
RatingBar ratingBar = new RatingBar(new ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.AppTheme_RatingBar), null, 0);
```