# How to set progressDrawable to a RatingBar dynamically using LayerDrawable

Tags: android, android-widget, android-drawable

I want to set **progressDrawable** to a **RatingBar**. I was able to do this using (layer-list) via xml. Here is my layout ....

```
<RatingBar
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
   android:stepSize="0.5"
   android:rating="3.0"
   android:id="@+id/ratingbar_default"
   android:progressDrawable="@drawable/star_rating_bar_full"
   />
```

Here is my [star_rating_bar_full](http://pastebin.com/j5WNQ34W)

where **star2** and **star1** are images for specifying rated star and unrated star.

The output was fine and the **RatingBar** looked great. I was able to rate also. Now i want to apply the same logic **dynamically** using **LayerDrawable**

I have tried to use the following answer [Dynamic RatingBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15027475/constructing-a-ratingbar-using-images-loaded-from-the-web). I was able to display the RatingBar but the edges were cut at the right side of Rating Bar. The functionality was working fine but this is the only problem i am facing.

Any ideas ??? Why the rating bar edges has been cut of at right side.