# Set initialized ratingbar style programmatically

Tags: android, rating

I'm able to create customized icon for rating bar, but I would like to add different rating bar in different situation programmatically.

Is there any way to achieve this rather than initialize in xml file?

Comment: You can use the third constructor for `RatingBar`, `RatingBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)` where you define the style resource

Comment: Is it possible if I create the ratingbar in mylayout.xml, but want to apply style in code?

Comment: Not as far as I know. You could explore `setProgressDrawable(int)` with the following answer to help with the creation of the drawables: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15027475/constructing-a-ratingbar-using-images-loaded-from-the-web

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution

```
ContextThemeWrapper contextThemeWrapper = new ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.ProfileRatingBar);
RatingBar rate = new RatingBar(contextThemeWrapper, null, 0);
```

`R.style.ProfileRatingBar` is my custom ratingbar. Code below

```
<style name="ProfileRatingBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.RatingBar">
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/profile_ratingbar</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">24dp</item>
    <item name="android:maxHeight">24dp</item>
</style>
```

Hope this helps you.