# How to tranfer image to other activity using bundle Android Studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, android-recyclerview

Here I want to ask how to send data retrieved from the database from the RecyclerViewAdapter to another activity (UpdateActivity).

This is my RecyclerViewAdapter which will send the image

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.Filterable;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.bumptech.glide.load.DecodeFormat;
import com.bumptech.glide.request.BaseRequestOptions;
import com.bumptech.glide.request.RequestOptions;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder>{

    private ArrayList<data_mahasiswa> listMahasiswa;

    private Context context;

    //    Interface delete data
    public interface dataLinstener{
        void onDeleteData(data_mahasiswa data, int position);
    }

    dataLinstener linstener;

    //    konstruktor input data
    public RecyclerViewAdapter(ArrayList<data_mahasiswa> listMahasiswa, Context context) {
        this.listMahasiswa = listMahasiswa;
        this.context = context;
//        delete fungsi listener
        linstener = (ListData)context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.view_design, parent,false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        //        Mengambil Nilai/Value yang terdapat pada rcview berdasarkan posisi
        final String gambar = listMahasiswa.get(position).getGambar();

        final String NIM = listMahasiswa.get(position).getNim();
        final String Nama = listMahasiswa.get(position).getNama();
        final String Fakultas = listMahasiswa.get(position).getFakultas();
        final String Prodi = listMahasiswa.get(position).getProdi();
        final String Tanggal = listMahasiswa.get(position).getTanggal_lahir();
        final String Phone = listMahasiswa.get(position).getPhone();
        final String Email = listMahasiswa.get(position).getEmail();
        final String IPK = listMahasiswa.get(position).getIpk();
        final String Alamat = listMahasiswa.get(position).getAlamat();
        final String Golongan_Darah = listMahasiswa.get(position).getGolonggan_darah();
        final String Jenis_Kelamin = listMahasiswa.get(position).getJenis_kelamin();


//        mengisi nilai

        BaseRequestOptions requestOptions = (RequestOptions) ((RequestOptions) ((RequestOptions) ((RequestOptions) ((RequestOptions) new RequestOptions().format(DecodeFormat.PREFER_ARGB_8888)).override(Integer.MIN_VALUE)).placeholder((int) R.color.purple_200)).centerCrop()).fitCenter();
        if (gambar == null) {
            holder.Gambar.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_person_100);
            ViewHolder viewHolder = holder;
            String str = NIM;
        } else {
            Glide.with(holder.itemView.getContext()).load(gambar.toString().trim()).apply(requestOptions).into(holder.Gambar);
        }

        holder.NIM.setText("NIM \t\t\t\t: " + NIM);
        holder.Nama.setText("Nama \t\t\t: " + Nama);
        holder.Fakultas.setText("Fakultas \t\t: " + Fakultas);
        holder.Prodi.setText("Prodi \t\t\t: " + Prodi);
        holder.Tanggal.setText("Tanggal \t\t: " + Tanggal);
        holder.Phone.setText("No Phone \t: " + Phone);
        holder.Email.setText("Email \t\t\t: " + Email);
        holder.IPK.setText("IPK \t\t\t\t: " + IPK);
        holder.Alamat.setText("Alamat \t\t: " + Alamat);
        holder.Golongan_Darah.setText("Golongan Darah \t\t: " + Golongan_Darah);
        holder.Jenis_Kelamin.setText("Jenis Kelamin \t\t\t: " + Jenis_Kelamin);

        holder.ListItem.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                final String[] action = {"Update","Delete"};
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext());
                builder.setItems(action, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        switch (which){
                            case 0:
//                        aktivity update / fungsi update
                                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                                bundle.putString("dataNIM", listMahasiswa.get(position).getNim());
                                bundle.putString("dataNama", listMahasiswa.get(position).getNama());
//                                Menggunakan spinner
                                bundle.putString("dataFakultas", listMahasiswa.get(position).getFakultas());
                                bundle.putString("dataProdi",listMahasiswa.get(position).getProdi());

                                bundle.putString("dataTanggal", listMahasiswa.get(position).getTanggal_lahir());
                                bundle.putString("dataPhone",listMahasiswa.get(position).getPhone());
                                bundle.putString("dataEmail",listMahasiswa.get(position).getEmail());
                                bundle.putString("dataIPK",listMahasiswa.get(position).getIpk());
                                bundle.putString("dataAlamat",listMahasiswa.get(position).getAlamat());
//                        kurang golongan darah dan gender / menggunakan radio
                                bundle.putString("dataGolongan_Darah",listMahasiswa.get(position).getGolonggan_darah());
                                bundle.putString("dataJenis_Kelamin",listMahasiswa.get(position).getJenis_kelamin());
//                        gambar
                                **bundle.putString("dataGambar",listMahasiswa.get(position).getGambar());**
//                        primary key
                                bundle.putString("getPrimaryKey",listMahasiswa.get(position).getKey());
                                Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), UpdateActivity.class);
                                intent.putExtras(bundle);
                                context.startActivity(intent);



                                break;
                            case 1:
                                linstener.onDeleteData(listMahasiswa.get(position), position);
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                });
                builder.create();
                builder.show();
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listMahasiswa.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private TextView NIM, Nama, Fakultas, Prodi, Tanggal, Phone, Email, IPK, Alamat, Golongan_Darah, Jenis_Kelamin;
        private ImageView Gambar;

        private LinearLayout ListItem;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            Gambar = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivGambar);

            NIM = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvNim);
            Nama = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvNama);
            Fakultas= itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvFakultas);
            Prodi= itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvProdi);
            Tanggal= itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTanggal);
            Phone= itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvPhone);
            Email = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvEmail);
            IPK= itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvIPK);
            Alamat = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvAlamat);
            Golongan_Darah= itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvGolongan_Darah);
            Jenis_Kelamin= itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvJenis_Kelamin);
            ListItem = itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_items);

        }
    }

}
```

and this is the activity that will receive the image (UpdateActivity)

```
package com.example.presentasi;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.UUID;

import static android.text.TextUtils.isEmpty;

public class UpdateActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //    tambahan spinner
    private String[] ListProdi,ListFakultas;

    private Button Update;
    private EditText NIM, Nama, Phone, Email, IPK, Alamat,Tanggal;
    private Spinner Fakultas, Prodi;
    private ImageButton PilihGambar;
    private ImageView ViewGambar;
    private CheckBox gdA, gdB, gdAB, gdO;
    private RadioButton Pria, Wanita;

    private String cekNIM,cekNama,cekPhone,cekEmail,cekIPK,cekAlamat;
    private DatabaseReference getReference;

    //    tanggal
    Calendar calendar;
    DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog;

    //    image pilih
    private Bitmap bitmap;
    private Uri gambarUri;


//    Upload
    private String getNIM,getNama,getPhone,getEmail,getIPK,getAlamat,getFakultas,getProdi,getTanggal_Lahir,getGambar,getJenis_Kelamin,getGolongan_Darah;
    private StorageReference reference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_update);

        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Update Data");
//        Button
        Update = findViewById(R.id.btUpdate);
        Tanggal = findViewById(R.id.btTanggal);
//        EditText
        NIM = findViewById(R.id.etNim);
        Nama = findViewById(R.id.etNama);
        Phone = findViewById(R.id.etPhone);
        Email = findViewById(R.id.etEmail);
        IPK = findViewById(R.id.etIpk);
        Alamat = findViewById(R.id.etAlamat);
//        Spinner
        Fakultas = findViewById(R.id.spFakultas);
        Prodi= findViewById(R.id.spProdi);
//        Image
        ViewGambar = findViewById(R.id.ivGambar);
        PilihGambar = findViewById(R.id.ibGambar);
//        Checkbox
        gdA = findViewById(R.id.cbA);
        gdB = findViewById(R.id.cbB);
        gdAB = findViewById(R.id.cbAB);
        gdO = findViewById(R.id.cbO);
//        RadioButton
        Pria = findViewById(R.id.rbPria);
        Wanita= findViewById(R.id.rbWanita);

        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        getReference = database.getReference();
        getData();

        Update.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                getNIM = NIM.getText().toString();
                getNama = Nama.getText().toString();
                getPhone = Phone.getText().toString();
                getEmail = Email.getText().toString();
                getIPK = IPK.getText().toString();
                getAlamat = Alamat.getText().toString();
                getFakultas = Fakultas.getSelectedItem().toString();
                getProdi = Prodi.getSelectedItem().toString();

                if (gdA.isChecked()){
                    getGolongan_Darah = gdA.getText().toString();
                    gdB.setChecked(false);
                    gdAB.setChecked(false);
                    gdO.setChecked(false);
                }else {
                }if(gdB.isChecked()){
                    getGolongan_Darah = gdB.getText().toString();
                    gdA.setChecked(false);
                    gdAB.setChecked(false);
                    gdO.setChecked(false);
                }else {
                }if (gdAB.isChecked()){
                    getGolongan_Darah = gdAB.getText().toString();
                    gdA.setChecked(false);
                    gdB.setChecked(false);
                    gdO.setChecked(false);
                }else {
                }if (gdO.isChecked()){
                    getGolongan_Darah = gdO.getText().toString();
                    gdA.setChecked(false);
                    gdAB.setChecked(false);
                    gdB.setChecked(false);
                }else {
                }

                if(Pria.isChecked()){
                    getJenis_Kelamin = Pria.getText().toString();
                }else {

                }if(Wanita.isChecked()){
                    getJenis_Kelamin = Wanita.getText().toString();
                }

                getTanggal_Lahir = Tanggal.getText().toString();

                Toast.makeText(UpdateActivity.this,"Upload Data",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                checkUser();

            }

        });

        //        Date Picker
        Tanggal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                int hari = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                int bulan = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                int tahun = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);

                datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(UpdateActivity.this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                        Tanggal.setText(dayOfMonth + "/" + (month + 1) + "/" + year);
                    }
                }, hari,bulan,tahun);
                datePickerDialog.show();
            }
        });

        PilihGambar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                UpdateActivity.this.getimage();
            }
        });

    }

    private void getData(){

        **int resId =  getIntent().getExtras().getInt("dataGambar");**
        **ViewGambar.setImageResource(resId); **

        final String getNIM = getIntent().getExtras().getString("dataNIM");
        final String getNama = getIntent().getExtras().getString("dataNama");


//        spinner
        final String getFakultas = getIntent().getExtras().getString("dataFakultas");
        final String getProdi = getIntent().getExtras().getString("dataProdi");

        ListFakultas = new String[]{"Ilmukomputer","Ekonomi"};
        ArrayAdapter<String> fakultasadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item,ListFakultas);
        Fakultas.setAdapter(fakultasadapter);
        Fakultas.setSelection(fakultasadapter.getPosition(getFakultas.trim()));

        ListProdi = new String[]{"Informatika","Sistem Informasi","Bisnis Digital","Teknologi Informasi"};
        ArrayAdapter<String> prodiadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item,ListProdi);
        Prodi.setAdapter(prodiadapter);
        Prodi.setSelection(prodiadapter.getPosition(getProdi.trim()));


        final String getTanggal = getIntent().getExtras().getString("dataTanggal");
        final String getPhone = getIntent().getExtras().getString("dataPhone");
        final String getEmail = getIntent().getExtras().getString("dataEmail");
        final String getIPK = getIntent().getExtras().getString("dataIPK");
        final String getAlamat = getIntent().getExtras().getString("dataAlamat");

//        mengambil data golongan dan jenis kelamin
        if ("A".equals(getIntent().getExtras().getString("dataGolongan_Darah"))){
            gdA.setChecked(true);
        }else if ("B".equals(getIntent().getExtras().getString("dataGolongan_Darah"))){
            gdB.setChecked(true);
        }else if ("AB".equals(getIntent().getExtras().getString("dataGolongan_Darah"))){
            gdAB.setChecked(true);
        }else if ("O".equals(getIntent().getExtras().getString("dataGolongan_Darah"))) {
            gdO.setChecked(true);
        }
        if ("Pria".equals(getIntent().getExtras().getString("dataJenis_Kelamin"))){
            Pria.setChecked(true);
        }else if ("Wanita".equals(getIntent().getExtras().getString("dataJenis_Kelamin"))){
            Wanita.setChecked(true);
        }


        NIM.setText(getNIM);
        Nama.setText(getNama);

        Tanggal.setText(getTanggal);
        Phone.setText(getPhone);
        Email.setText(getEmail);
        IPK.setText(getIPK);
        Alamat.setText(getAlamat);

    }

//    private void updateMahasiswa(data_mahasiswa mahasiswa){
//        String getKey = getIntent().getExtras().getString("getPrimaryKey");
//        getReference.child("Admin")
//                .child("Mahasiswa")
//                .child(getKey)
//                .setValue(mahasiswa)
//                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
//                    @Override
//                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
//                        NIM.setText("");
//                        Nama.setText("");
//                        Phone.setText("");
//                        Email.setText("");
//                        IPK.setText("");
//                        Alamat.setText("");
//                        Tanggal.setText("");
//                        Toast.makeText(UpdateActivity.this, "Data Terupdate", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//                        finish();
//                    }
//                });
//    }

    //    Pilih gambar
    private void getimage() {
        AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("Upload Image").setItems(new CharSequence[]{"Galeri"}, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                UpdateActivity.this.startActivityForResult(new Intent("android.intent.action.PICK", MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI), 2);
            }
        });
        dialog.create();
        dialog.show();
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == 2 && resultCode == -1 && data != null) {
            try {
                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), data.getData());
            }catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Uri data2 = data.getData();
            this.gambarUri = data2;
            this.ViewGambar.setImageURI(data2);
        }
    }

    private void checkUser(){
        if(isEmpty(getNIM) && isEmpty(getNama) && isEmpty(getTanggal_Lahir) && isEmpty(getPhone) && isEmpty(getEmail) && isEmpty(getIPK) && isEmpty(getAlamat)) {
            Toast.makeText(UpdateActivity.this, "Data tidak boleh ada yang kosong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            String getKey = getIntent().getExtras().getString("getPrimaryKey");
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,stream);
            reference.child("gambar/"+(UUID.randomUUID() + ".jpg")).putBytes(stream.toByteArray()).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    taskSnapshot.getStorage().getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                            UpdateActivity.this.getReference.child("Admin").child("Mahasiswa").child(getKey)
                                    .setValue(new com.example.presentasi.data_mahasiswa(getNIM, getNama, getFakultas, getProdi, getGolongan_Darah, getJenis_Kelamin, getTanggal_Lahir, getPhone, getEmail, getIPK, getAlamat, uri.toString().trim()))
                                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                            NIM.setText("");
                                            Nama.setText("");
                                            Fakultas.setSelection(0);
                                            Prodi.setSelection(0);

                                            if(gdA.isChecked()){
                                                gdA.setChecked(false);
                                            }else if (gdB.isChecked()){
                                                gdB.setChecked(false);
                                            }else if (gdAB.isChecked()){
                                                gdAB.setChecked(false);
                                            }else if (gdO.isChecked()){
                                                gdO.setChecked(false);
                                            }

                                            if(Pria.isChecked()){
                                                Pria.setChecked(false);
                                            }else if(Wanita.isChecked()){
                                                Wanita.setChecked(false);
                                            }
                                            Tanggal.setText("klik untuk memilih tanggal lahir");
                                            Phone.setText("");
                                            Email.setText("");
                                            IPK.setText("");
                                            Alamat.setText("");;
                                            Toast.makeText(UpdateActivity.this,"Upload Berhasil",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            UpdateActivity.this.ViewGambar.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_person_100);
                                            startActivity(new Intent(UpdateActivity.this,ListData.class));
                                        }
                                    });

                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    }


}
```

Here is the simple code
How do I send

```
                                bundle.putString("dataGambar",listMahasiswa.get(position).getGambar());
```

How do I receive

```
        int resId =  getIntent().getExtras().getInt("dataGambar");
        ViewGambar.setImageResource(resId);
```

Comment: Well what goes wrong? We cannot see what you send as what would be `listMahasiswa.get(position).getGambar()` ? But when it is a resource id integer it is ok.

Answer (score 0):

The way to transfer an image to another image is by converting the image to a byte array.

To do that we first have to convert the image to a Bitmap.

1. Converting image to bitmap

`Bitmap myLogo = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.my_drawable);`

Ref:[How to convert a Drawable image from resources to a Bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15255611/how-to-convert-a-drawable-image-from-resources-to-a-bitmap/15255786)

2. Convert Bitmap to Byte Array

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
```

Ref:[converting Java bitmap to byte array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4989182/converting-java-bitmap-to-byte-array)

3. Pass array to intent

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(this, NextActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("picture", byteArray);
startActivity(intent);
```

4. get tha value in next activity

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
byte[] byteArray = extras.getByteArray("picture");

Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

image.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```