# Why does it say "Bitmap cannot be resolved to a type" in this case?

Tags: android

I get this error. How can I fix this in my situation?

```
"Bitmap cannot be resolved to a type"
```

**The line where error occurs**

```
public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
```

**My code**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private Activity activity = this;
    private String title = "";

    private ActionBar mActionBar;


    private SimpleSideDrawer mNav;
    WebView myWebView;

    int width, height;
    float flick_width; 
    float flick_height;     

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

          title = activity.getTitle().toString(); // (1)
          requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);  

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        getSize();

        mActionBar = getActionBar();
        mActionBar.hide();


        mNav = new SimpleSideDrawer(this);
        mNav.setLeftBehindContentView(R.layout.activity_behind_left_simple, this);
        mNav.setRightBehindContentView(R.layout.activity_behind_right_simple, this);


        myWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                Log.d("HelloWebView", "onPageStarted : " + url);
                activity.setTitle("Loading..."); // (2)
                activity.setProgressBarVisibility(true);
            }
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                Log.d("HelloWebView", "onPageFinished : " + url);
            }
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                Log.d("HelloWebView", "shouldOverrideUrlLoading : " + url);
                return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
            }
            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                Log.d("HelloWebView", "onReceivedError : "+description);
                //view.loadData("Error   "+description, "text/plain", "utf-8");
                view.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, "Error ("+errorCode+"):"+description, "text/plain", "utf-8", null);
            }
        });
        myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() { // (3)
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
                activity.setProgress(progress * 100);
                   Log.d("HelloWebView", "progress="+progress);
                   if (progress==100) {
                       activity.setProgressBarVisibility(false);
                       activity.setTitle(title);
                   }
            }
        });

        myWebView.loadUrl("http://yahoo.com");          
        myWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true); 
        myWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        myWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
```

Comment: sure that the import of the bitmap (in the beginning of the file) is correct, meaning  : "android.graphics.Bitmap"

Comment: @androiddeveloper I'm on eclipse. It usually asks me to import, and I can do that by clicking it. But this time it won't ask me anything. How can I solve this?

Comment: sure the project propeties uses android correctly? try to create a totally new android project and create a bitmap in any of the possible ways, to see if it is ok.

Comment: what do you mean by saying properties? what part of properties?

Comment: for example, in the build path, you can see android as one of the items , right? the order of the items seems ok? have you also tried cleaning the project, restarting eclipse? updating eclipse,java 1.6, ADT &SDK ?

Comment: the version is all new. what else can I check? Do I need to have bitmap images in somewhere?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Eclipse sometimes hiccups when trying to auto-resolve imports. In cases like that, you can try manually entering the import statement yourself: `import android.graphics.Bitmap;`

Comment: I did this and there was no more error but the progress bar didn't show up:(

Comment: @MKK: That's some separate problem that you will need to debug.

Comment: @MKK , you wrote that you were sure it imported the right path in the question i've written... :(

Answer (score 7):

Just Click "Ctr+Shift+O" even though it doesnt show the import when you hover on it.. it will automatically import It when you click this --->> "Ctr+Shift+O"