# Android: combine multiple drawables into one dynamically?

Tags: android, android-drawable

lets say I want to make an app which lets user create avatar from choice of clothes/items and then let other users see these "avatars".
So what would be the best way to make this work? I was thinking of having these clothes/items as images, then save user avatars as numbers say: 4f6v31 which would translate into like:

```
4 = skin color.
f = face.
6 = shirt color.
v = pants color.
3 = shoes.
1 = hair.
```

Then when user receives say 5 of these "other peoples saved avatars" it would load all 5 avatars by combining those clothes/items images into one drawable.
Is such thing possible or is there better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Create a new Bitmap `Canvas`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#draw-with-canvas) of the appropriate size and then follow these steps:

1. [Load the lowest `Drawable` layer as a `Bitmap`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8717333/converting-drawable-resource-image-into-bitmap)
2. Create a [`PorterDuffColorFilter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PorterDuffColorFilter.html) with the user's selected color
3. [Paint the Bitmap to the output Canvas using the filter](http://android-er.blogspot.ca/2012/09/example-of-using-porterduffcolorfilter.html)
4. Repeat for the next lowest layer

Once every layer has been painted to the canvas, write it out to a [`BitmapDrawable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/BitmapDrawable.html#BitmapDrawable(android.content.res.Resources,%20android.graphics.Bitmap)) and apply to an `ImageView`.